# Convert 12hour time to 24Hour time

Tags: r, time

I have hourly weather data.  I've seen the function examples from here: http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/991

I'm altering the code to account for airport data, which has a different URL type.  Another issue with the airport weather data is that the time data is saved in 12 hour format.  Here is a sample of the data:

```
14  10:43 AM
15  10:54 AM
16  11:54 AM
17  12:07 PM
18  12:15 PM
19  12:54 PM
20  1:54 PM
21  2:54 PM
```

Here's what I attempted: (I see that using just 'PM' isn't careful enough because any times between 12 and 1 pm will be off if they go through this alg)

```
date<-Sys.Date()


data$TimeEST<-strsplit(data$TimeEST, ' ')
for (x in 1:35){
    if('AM' %in% data$TimeEST[[x]]){
        gsub('AM','',data$TimeEST[[x]])
        data$TimeEST[[x]]<-str_trim(data$TimeEST[[x]])
        data$TimeEST[[x]]<-str_c(date,' ',data$TimeEST[x],':',data$TimeEST[2])
    }
    else if('PM' %in% data$TimeEST[[x]]){
        data$TimeEST[[x]]<-gsub('PM', '',data$TimeEST[[x]])
        data$TimeEST[[x]]<-strsplit(data$TimeEST[[x]], ':')
        data$TimeEST[[x]][[1]][1]<-as.integer(data$TimeEST[[x]][[1]][1])+12
        data$TimeEST[[x]]<-str_trim(data$TimeEST[[x]][[1]])
        data$TimeEST[[x]]<-str_c(date, " ", data$TimeEST[[x]][1],':',data$TimeEST[[x]][2])

    }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Would `strptime` work?

```
df2= structure(c("10:43 AM", "10:54 AM", "11:54 AM", "12:07 PM", "12:15 PM", 
            "12:54 PM", "1:54 PM", "2:54 PM"), .Dim = c(8L, 1L))



 strptime(df2, "%I:%M %p" )
```

Or in case you don't want the date, something like:
Although it depends what kind of class would you want for the object.

```
substr(strptime(df2, "%I:%M %p" ),11,19)
```

Comment: the date issue is actually rather large.  I would like the date/time information to be an object that can be placed into a zoo object, but larger than that the main goal of the function is to return data for a specific day.  If I lose that date information, which granted is not in the column to begin with, I will be causing future headaches.  The date information is provided by the user when they input a date range into the initial function.  For each day in that range a website is read and then the data is cleaned.  Part of the cleaning is converting from 12 to 24 hour time.  Thanks again

Comment: `# convert Time column into properly encoded date time <br/>`
        `data$TimeEST <- strptime(data$TimeEST, format='%I:%M %p')`<br/>
        `data$TimeEST <- substr(data$TimeEST, 11, 19)`
        `data$TimeEST <- str_c(date,data$TimeEST)`
        `data$TimeEST <- as.POSIXlt(data$TimeEST, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`  @AndresT thanks for the suggestions this is what I used to get my desired object type.

Answer (score 4):

take a look at `?strptime`.

```
as.POSIXct(data$TimeEST, format='%I:%M %p')
```