# Convert text dd-mmm-yyyy hh.mm.ssss AM/PM to date

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have imported a file with a date string in the form of `dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`.

1. I am struggling to find R code that converts this to date time format where the time part is 24 hour format, and
2. how do I create a new variable with only the date.

AS an example of one of the dates see below:
`26-AUG-2016 08.48.43.65483000 AM`

It seems that seconds also have decimals.

R version 3.3.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864659/convert-12hour-time-to-24hour-time , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833538/convert-12-hour-character-time-to-24-hour ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making use of the [**`lubridate`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) package:

```
lubridate::mdy_hms("01/22/2013 11:00:00 PM")
```

this would produce:

```
[1] "2013-01-22 23:00:00 UTC"
```

The returned object is of the `"POSIXct"/"POSIXt"` classes so you should be able to manipulate it conveniently if you wish to get dates or extract time:

```
>> as.Date(lubridate::mdy_hms("01/22/2013 11:00:00 PM"))
[1] "2013-01-22"
```

Comment: Thank you. the date is in a column in the data set called SYS_DATE. Would the command then be roapr$newdate <- as.Date(lubridate::mdy_hms(roapr$SYS_DATE))

Comment: When running this command I get the following error message: All formats failed to parse. No formats found

Comment: @Manfred Clearly, there are more formats in your column than within the provided example. Make your post reproducible by providing sufficient data and, I bet, that it will be answered.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `strptime` with proper format

```
strptime("26-AUG-2016 08.48.43.65483000 AM", "%d-%b-%Y %H.%M.%OS %p")
#[1] "2016-08-26 08:48:43 IST"
```

and if you only want the date we can wrap it in `format`

```
format(strptime("26-AUG-2016 08.48.43.65483000 AM", "%d-%b-%Y %H.%M.%OS %p"), 
                                                                    "%d-%m-%Y")
#[1] "26-08-2016"
```

and to get only the time,

```
format(strptime("26-AUG-2016 08.48.43.65483000 AM", "%d-%b-%Y %I.%M.%OS %p"), 
                                                                     "%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "08:48:43"

format(strptime("26-AUG-2016 08.48.43.65483000 PM", "%d-%b-%Y %I.%M.%OS %p"), 
                                                                     "%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "20:48:43"
```

Comment: is the 0S a zero or the character o

Comment: @Manfred it is character O and not zero.

Comment: I have a dataset call roapr16. In it there us the column sys_date. When I run the comment roapr16$sys_date <- strptime("roapr16$sys_date", "%d-%b-%Y %H.%M.%OS %p") I get an error. The system literally hangs

Comment: You don't need quotes in there. Try `strptime(roapr16$sys_date, "%d-%b-%Y %H.%M.%OS %p")`

Comment: Ran the following code: roapr16$newdate <- strptime(roapr$SYS_Date, "%d-%b-%Y %H.%M.%S %p") The code gives an error message as follows: warning message: In '[<-data.table' (x, j =name, value=value) : Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 30 items of column 'newdate' (recycled leaving remainder of 8 columns).